# Combo box Select2 View doesn't view properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

In my web application, I'm adding new rows to the table from JavaScript.

There is an  element in the row and for the  I'm loading data from the ViewBag.

Also, I wanted to add Select2 class to the same  element.

This is my current code.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>MEASURE BY</th>
        <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
        <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
      <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

This is the javascript

```
var counter = 1;

var dropdownOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Item_ID));

$(function () {
  $("#add").click(function () {
    var newRow = $(
       '<tr id="tablerow' +
       counter +
       '" class ="poSet"> ' +
       "<td>" +
       '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
       counter +
       "</strong></label>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="40%">' +
       '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select ItemId" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
       counter +
       ']" id="ItemId[' + counter + ']" required="required" ' +
       "</select>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" onchange="calQtyBase(this)" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  onchange="priceBase(this)" data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       "<td>" +
       '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
       counter +
       ');">x</button>' +
       "</td>" +
       "</tr>"
     );
    
    var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); 

    dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {
      var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
      selectElement.append(optionElement);
    });

    newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");

    selectElement.select2();

    counter++;
    return false;
  });
});
```

So when I add this, the view comes as this

[image]

When I 1st add the data element width comes with the default and then onwards it changes.

There is also an issue in the view of the **Select 2** combo box. I think missing a form-control class or something, it looks like a combo box without the CSS.

How do I fix these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) drop downs fill up the available width, the easiest option is to add `width:100%` to the select2 parameters:

```
selectElement.select2({width:"100%"});
```

There are other options such as setting the style=, but IMO the above is the easiest and most consistent.

If your [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) looks like a normal `select` then it probably is a normal select and hasn't had select2 applied - alternatively, the css may not have loaded correct (eg wrong/blocked path) - or may have conflicting css if you have another css library (eg bootstrap) so you may need additional css tweaks/plugins; depending on the exact issue - it should do *something* though.

Note that [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) needs additional parameters if your select is in some sort of dialog (it affects the drop-down itself, this doesn't appear to be your issue, just noting it)

In the snippet below, it's working as expected.

Updated snippet:

```js
var counter = 1;

var dropdownOptions = [{ Value:'1', Text:'one' }, { Value:'2', Text:'two' }];

$(function () {
  $("#add").click(function () {
    var newRow = $(
       '<tr id="tablerow' +
       counter +
       '" class ="poSet"> ' +
       "<td>" +
       '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
       counter +
       "</strong></label>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="40%">' +
       '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select ItemId" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
       counter +
       ']" id="ItemId[' + counter + ']" required="required" ' +
       "</select>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" onchange="calQtyBase(this)" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  onchange="priceBase(this)" data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       "<td>" +
       '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
       counter +
       ');">x</button>' +
       "</td>" +
       "</tr>"
     );
    
    var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); 

    dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {
      var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
      selectElement.append(optionElement);
    });

    newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");

    selectElement.select2({width:"100%"});

    counter++;
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>MEASURE BY</th>
        <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
        <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
      <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </p>
</div>
```